# Why is this dependency not loading correctly through Composer autoloader?

Tags: php, wordpress, dependencies, composer-php, autoload

I'm working on a WordPress [plugin](https://github.com/liquidchurch/lqd-messages) that has a dependency on [WDS-Shortcodes](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/WDS-Shortcodes).

I've bundled the dependency into my plugin in a `/libs/wds-shortcodes/` directory.

In my `composer.json` I have:

```
...
"autoload": {
  "classmap": [
    ...
   ],
  "files": [
    ...
    "libs/wds-shortcodes/wds-shortcodes.php",
    ...
  ]
...
```

Why am I mapping just the one filed instead of `/libs/wds-shortcodes/`? Because WDS-Shortcodes uses a loader in `wds-shortcodes.php` that determines if this is the latest version of wds-shortcodes that has been loaded and only loads itself if it is. This file then takes care of autoloading all the other files.

In my understanding, mapping `/libs/wds-shortcodes/` would cause the classes to load no matter what, undermining the loader functionality and possibly causing conflicts.

In any case, after running `composer install` and attempting to load the site with the plugin I get errors, namely:

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'WDS_Shortcodes' not found in /srv/www/wordpress-two/public_html/wp-content/plugins/lqd-messages/includes/shortcodes/class-shortcodes-run-base.php on line 7

So it seems that the dependency is not loading because the dependency wrongly thinks another version of it that is as current/more current is currently running (but it isn't, as seen by the fact that my plugin can't find the class when needed).

I've been battling around this dependencies issue for innumerable hours (across multiple days) now. It changes form as I try different approaches but remains essentially the same. I've googled and read stackoverflow threads all over the place to no avail, hoping someone can help me figure this out.

## Update #1

While I've looked over the autoloader a number of times, @Nico Haase's Q prompted me to push in this direction again.

The plugin I'm working on is a fork of this [plugin](https://github.com/jtsternberg/GC-Sermons). Its been quite a while since we forked but I went back to the original repo and grabbed the latest "installable" version of the plugin (not the repo itself, just the [gc-sermons.zip](https://github.com/jtsternberg/GC-Sermons/blob/master/gc-sermons.zip) file). I then compared the autoloader for the original to my fork and noticed that there are differences.

The `autoload_files.php` files are similar. The main difference being that I moved the wds-shortcodes dependency into a /libs folder and out of Composer. So the path in the original is:

`$vendorDir . '/webdevstudios/wds-shortcodes.php'`

In mine it is:

`$baseDir . '/libs/wds-shortcodes/wds-shortcodes.php'`

The larger change occurs in the classmaps found in `autoload_classmap.php` and `autoload_static.php`. In the original the wds-shortcodes portion looks like this:

```
'WDS_Shortcode' => $vendorDir . '/webdevstudios/wds-shortcodes/includes/shortcode.php',
'WDS_Shortcode_Admin' => $vendorDir . '/webdevstudios/wds-shortcodes/includes/shortcode-admin.php',
'WDS_Shortcode_Instances' => $vendorDir . '/webdevstudios/wds-shortcodes/includes/shortcode-instances.php',
'WDS_Shortcodes' => $vendorDir . '/webdevstudios/wds-shortcodes/includes/shortcodes.php',
'WDS_Shortcodes_Base' => $vendorDir . '/webdevstudios/wds-shortcodes/includes/init.php',
```

Whereas my `autoload_classmap.php` includes no reference to any `WDS_Shortcodes` classes, only the `autoload_files.php` and the `autoload_static.php` (in the files portion).

I have been able to make my autoloader look like the original autoloader by adding to the `composer.json` file:

```
"autoload": {
  "classmap": [
    ...
    "libs/wds-shortcodes/includes/"
    ...
  ]
}
```

However, as noted above (1st paragraph after 1st code example), I think this undermines the way WDS-Shortcodes is supposed to work - that is, the loader built into WDS-Shortcodes checks to ensure no other version of the dependency is loaded and if it is that the current version is more recent and only loads itself if one or the other of these is true.

So, it seems to me, that GC-Sermons is bypassing the functionality of WDS-Shortcodes to load itself conditionally...or am I misreading things?

The other thing that confuses me is how exactly Composer knows to add the additional classes GC-Sermons is loading but doesn't know the same when loading WDS-Shortcodes in my instance.

GC-Sermons doesn't explicitly say to include the `wds-shortcodes/includes` directory either, but for some reason it is automatically handled.

In the GC-Sermons `composer.json` the dependency is like so:

```
"require": {
  ...
  "webdevstudios/wds-shortcodes": "^v1.0.7",
  ...
}
```

And the only reference to explicitly loading part of the dependency is:

```
"autoload": {
  ...
  "files": [
    ...
    "vendor/webdevstudios/wds-shortcodes/wds-shortcodes.php"
    ...
   ]
}
```

Which is exactly what is in my `composer.json` as well.

And what about the dependency itself's `composer.json`? It includes no reference to autoloading itself, only to two of its own dependencies.

So why is Composer adding the classes to the classmap in the original but not in my case?

And is there a way to load this dependency with Composer autoloading that doesn't override the built-in conditional loading of WDS-Shortcodes?

Comment: Have a look at `vendor/composer`, that's the folder where all autoloading stuff resides. Is your shortcodes file listed there?

Comment: Thanks @NicoHaase for the question - it spurred me on to further exploration. I've added an entirely new section under UPDATE #1 that details my findings. There is a problem with the class appearing in the autoloader...but that isn't the whole story...see update. :)